# Why is a global variable called when there is a local variable?

Tags: java, methods, global-variables, local-variables

Give the EXACT output generated by the Java code shown below.

```
int x=1, y=-5, z=4; // global variables
int vals[] = {-6,2,-4,-8 ,-2,-3}; // global variables

public void setValues()
{
  char y = 'R';
  z=10;
  System.out.println("l1: "+x+" "+y+" "+z);

  y=call1(x,y,z);
  System.out.println("l2: "+x+" "+y+" "+z);

  x=call2(x,vals);
  System.out.println("l3: "+x+" "+y+" "+z);

  for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
      System.out.println("l"+(i+4)+": "+vals[i*2]);
 }

public char call1(int a, char b, int c)
{
    if (a >= c) return b;
    else
    {  
     c=15;
     z=25;
     return 'M'; // note the single quotes
    }
}

public int call2(int x, int [] anArray)
{
  int y = 0;
  for (int i=anArray.length-1; i>=0; i--)
  {
      if (anArray[i] > x)
      {
        anArray[i] = x + 5;y++;}
      }
      x = 100;
  return y; 
}
```

I provided the output for the first line which is `"l1: 1 R 10"`. I provided `"l2: 1 M 10"` for the second line, but was told it was `"l2: 1 M 25"`. I was told the local variables override the global (not best practice to use the same name). Nevertheless, z is set to 10 (locally) in setValues and referenced in the first line. I know the global z is set to 25 from call1, but when executing the second print, I thought it would still refer to setValues' (local) z=10, not the global's z=25. Am I seeing that wrong?

Comment: What local z are you talking about? There is no second local variable.

Comment: Local variables only override global variables when they are **redefined** locally not when they are set locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> […] z is set to 10 (locally) in setValues […] setValues' (local) z=10 […]

`setValues` does not have a local variable `z`; whenever it refers to the variable `z`, it's referring to the field (the "global variable").

For it to have a local variable `z`, this line:

```
  z=10;
```

would be changed to this:

```
  int z=10;
```

Comment: I did not notice that z wasn't re-created again in the setValues method, like y was (switched from int to char). This is my professors idea of being "tricky"... it is very much appreciated. Thanks.